# Center Footer Image For Mobile

Tags: css, mobile, footer

How can I center my footer image when viewed by a mobile device? As it shows now, on an iPhone, the footer image is not centered.

http://driftcoffeehouse.com/test/

```
#footer .secondary {
  background-image: url("http://driftcoffeehouse.com/test/wp- content/uploads/2014/02/footerbar.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-top: medium none;
  margin: -13px 0;
  padding: 30px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add a JSFiddle with your specific problem, your link will not be up forever and therefore won't help other users.

Comment: Post the relevant code here, so that we might be able to figure stuff out. As it stands, the HTML and CSS code relevant to your image would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it. I added this, `background-position: top center;`, to the `#footer .secondary` rule.

```
#footer .secondary {
  background-image: url("http://driftcoffeehouse.com/test/wp- content/uploads/2014/02/footerbar.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-top: medium none;
  margin: -13px 0;
  padding: 30px 0 0;
  background-position: top center;
}
```

Worked for me.  Tell me if you have trouble implementing it. Hope this helped, if not just message me by commenting below my answer. :)

### Edit:

[Fiddle with the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/VRqr9/) (Try resizing the fiddle pane to see the problem.)

[Fiddle without the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/VRqr9/1/)

Well there's the necessary stuff to replicate the problem and show the solution.